# Deciding whether or not a plot shows a decreasing trend

Tags: statistics, functions, graphing-functions, matlab

I have a sample of size 218 and I created a graph for a specific function using the plot command in MATLAB software.

I cannot decide whether this plot below shows a decreasing trend or no trend.

[image: Plot of some data]

Can anyone provide an insight?

Comment: From a purely qualitative standpoint it seems decreasing to me. If you want to take the human element out of it, why not just have MATLAB fit a trend line and see if that's decreasing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You mean there is a function that  helps to decide about the trend?

Comment: Plotting trend lines is a feature included in most plot graphing software. I'm not familiar with matlab, but googling around (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18486-trend-line-calculation-and-display) suggests you should go to tools > basic fitting.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I will check that feature.

Answer (score 1):

For this data,
I would suggest using
a moving average
with window size
10 to 50
and see what the result 
looks like
for the different
window sizes.

This is a standard method
for smoothing
oscillating data.